# header div background 100% width with fixed height

Tags: html, css

This is what is happening with the code.

[image]

Here is the code...

```
<div style="background-image: url(img/background.jpg);background-repeat: no-repeat; height:250px;"></div>
```

The size of the image is 963w x 200h.

At the end of the day, i would want this to be 100% width, but also be responsive for all devices. How can I make that happen?

adding `background-size:cover;` wont do that trick.

Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/t7ekj0mh/

Comment: width:100%; for width, height:100vh; for height. also Is there <meta name = "viewport" content = "width = device-width, initial-scale = 1.0"> and You can use <div class="imageArea><img width="100%" height="100%"></div> instead of background

Comment: i have the viewport. <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no"> .... but, what you stated doesnt work also. is takes everything i have below that div and pushes it down. and also doesnt make the background width 100%, itll make the div 100%.

Answer (score 0):

### Add `background size` [`contain`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size) for the image to scale horizontally

As I understand, this is what you are attempting to achieve.

```css
div{
  background: #E6DCDD url(https://i.ibb.co/2jCzQB6/background2.jpg)  center bottom / contain no-repeat;
  height: 300px;
  border: 5px dashed red;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

This will stretch the image horizontally and place it at the bottom, and by adding a color, it will seem as it is a one-piece thing.

Answer (score 0):

Add the rule `background-size: contain` to your `div`.

```html
<html>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/3/w3.css">
<body>

<div style="background-image: url(https://i.ibb.co/2jCzQB6/background2.jpg);background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: contain; height:250px;"></div>

</body>
</html>
```